# How to validate JavaFX CSS in advance?

Tags: java, css, validation, javafx

I have an app where the web admin interface allows to edit and customize the CSS that will be used on the JavaFX client (the client is a kiosk-type app running on public touch screens).

I would like to offer some degree of validation of the CSS input from the user before storing it in the DB and sending it to the JavaFX client.

My first (admittedly very naive) attempt was to create a JavaFX `Scene` and apply to it the CSS string I got from the HTTP request, and catch any exception resulting from it :

```
try {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Region());
    scene.getStylesheets().add(profile.getStylesheet());
}catch(Exception e){
    //send some validation message
}
```

But there are 2 problems with this approach :

- We are not in a JavaFX app, so I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = http-bio-8080-exec-2`
- Even if it worked all this code does with the CSS is add it to a `java.util.List' so I'm not sure it would raise an exception if we passed it invalid CSS

Is there a (preferably lightweight) way to validate, in a web container context, a piece of CSS destined to be applies to a JavaFX scene graph ?

Comment: e(fx)clipse has meta information we use for auto-completetion and validation of JavaFX CSS files in theory this all can be run as well in a headless none eclipse environment but it would involve some work to get it running.

The code is under EPL and can be found at http://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/ but stackoverflow is the wrong forum to discuss how you'd go get it running

Comment: @tomsontom interesting. I had a quick look but as far as I can tell, the parsing and validation code has a lot of dependencies on UI classes, other Eclipse libraries, Osgi environment etc. Pretty hard to extract just the needed logic I guess---

Comment: The core stuff that has all the parsing does not depend on OSGi but on Xtext & Antlr - as I said one has to put some effort it making it run outside the IDE but it is certainly doable

Comment: OK, I found some of the related packages, that are generated by Xtext. I'd like to dive into this but I fear it is beyond the range of this project (I would have to get familiar with both Xtext and antlr and the underlying concepts). Thanks anyway!